# How do I read all lines in a file into a tuple?

Tags: elixir

I need to randomly access all the words in an English dictionary file ("/usr/share/dict/words")  where each word is in one line.

Now, I'd like to access all these words in random order, for which I'd like to read the file into a tuple that allows random access.

I know I can read the file into a list like this:

```
words = 
  File.stream!("/usr/share/dict/words") 
  |> Stream.map(&String.trim_trailing/1) 
  |> Enum.to_list
```

But that does not let me access the words in random order. How could I read the file into a tuple instead?

(Alternatively, if there is another way to do this i.e. read the words in random order, please let me know)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "random order" and "random access" ? I am reasonably sure a Tuple is not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

List.to_tuple converts a list into a tuple, so the following works:

```
words = 
  File.stream!("/usr/share/dict/words") 
  |> Stream.map(&String.trim_trailing/1) 
  |> Enum.to_list
  |> List.to_tuple
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want them in a random order, how about:

```
words = 
  File.stream!("/usr/share/dict/words") 
  |> Stream.map(&String.trim_trailing/1) 
  |> Enum.to_list
  |> Enum.shuffle
```